# Need to set dropdown values and disable based on initial dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a configuration component with a set of 3 options.

The first dropdown includes 3 options. Anytime a user selects the option `Emulator` I need to set the value of the other two dropdowns to `none` and disable them.

I'm trying to accomplish using hooks but I'm not sure how to do it.

[image: Edit Q-56840430-BackgroundPanel]

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Row, Col, Modal } from "antd";
import AntCollapse from "./CustomCollapse";

const Body = styled.div`
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
`;

function warningShared() {
  Modal.warning({
    title: "Unsupported Configuration",
    content: (
      <div>
        <p>You cannot select shared options for an Emulator</p>
      </div>
    ),
    onOk() {}
  });
}

function warningStorage() {
  Modal.warning({
    title: "Unsupported Configuration",
    content: (
      <div>
        <p>You cannot select storage options for an Emulator</p>
      </div>
    ),
    onOk() {}
  });
}

const ConfigurationOptions = () => (
  <AntCollapse header="Membership Options">
    <Body>
      <h1>Game Membership Configurator</h1>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <h3>Perks Configuration</h3>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <p>Game Console</p>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4} offset={8}>
          <select
          onChange={warningShared}
          >
            <option>None</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>Emulator</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>Xbox</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>PlayStation</option>
          </select>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <p>Perks #1: Storage</p>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4} offset={8}>
          <select>
            <option>None</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>Basic</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>Advanced</option>
          </select>
        </Col>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Col span={12}>
          <p>Perks #2: Shared Accounts</p>
        </Col>
        <Col span={4} offset={8}>
          <select>
            <option>None</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>1 shared</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>5 shared</option>
            <option onSelect={null}>10 shared</option>
          </select>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Body>
  </AntCollapse>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<ConfigurationOptions />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most basic answer is that this is a job for React's `setState` hook, which allows you to stash an ever-changing value inside your component's scope, so you can reference and use it.

Here's a version of your code that implements this:

[image: Edit Q-56840430-BackgroundPanel]

Note that:

1. The `ConfigurationOptions` component's scope now has a concept of the `selectedConsole` and a way to `setSelectedConsole`.
2. The selection action has been moved to the `<select>` tag, which uses the (new) `value` attributes on the `<option>`s, rather than each `<option>` trying to handle its own click event. Relatedly, the value of each `select` group is now "controlled" by react, via the `value` attribute passed into the `<select>` tag. This is in contrast to the default "uncontrolled" behavior, wherein the `select` group tracks its own state internally.
3. The `<select>` also accommodates a `disabled` attribute, which you can link to the console value like so: `<select disabled={selectedConsole === "emulator"}>`. This doesn't produce very obvious disabled *styling* changes, but you'll note that those subsequent select fields no longer function. To add disabled styles, you could use the same trick to add a custom css `className` when the `<select>` is disabled.

edit: updated sandbox to include the clearing of the other selects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the state of each select in a useState hook or all combined in useReducer. Than you save the selections on the hooks within the onSelect callback. If the Emulator ist selected, clear the other values of the selects by clearing the hooks. To disable the selects, just add the disabled prop and check if the selected value marches your constraint.